# Model Aggregation : Extensions (Selection) not working after loadDocumentNode

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am loading an additional model using Viewer3D.loadDocumentNode (API v7) using the code below, which works great. However I have two issues:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(`urn:${myURN}`, (doc) => {
                var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
                viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables,{
                    placementTransform: (new THREE.Matrix4()).setPosition({x:0,y:0,z:0}),
                    keepCurrentModels: true,
                    globalOffset: {x:0,y:0,z:0}

                })
                .then( onLoadFinished );
            });
```

**1st issue**: My extension that waits on the SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT is no longer triggered after the aggregated model is loaded.

```
load() {
    this.onSelectionBinded = this.onSelectionEvent.bind(this);
    this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, this.onSelectionBinded);
    console.log('ReactToEvents has been loaded');
    return true;
}
```

example was from https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/events/

**2nd issue**: Another extension that parse selected elements doesn't take into account selected elements in the aggregated model (number of selections = 0)

```
onToolbarCreated() {
    // Create a new toolbar group if it doesn't exist
    this._group = this.viewer.toolbar.getControl('allMyAwesomeExtensionsToolbar');
    if (!this._group) {
        this._group = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('allMyAwesomeExtensionsToolbar');
        this.viewer.toolbar.addControl(this._group);
    }

    // Add a new button to the toolbar group
    this._button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('handleSelectionExtensionButton');
    this._button.onClick = (ev) => {
        // Get current selection
        const selection = this.viewer.getSelection();
        this.viewer.clearSelection();
        // Anything selected?
        console.log("Clicked handleSelectionExtensionButton: ", selection.length);
        if (selection.length > 0) { ... }
    }
}
```

For some reason `this.viewer.getSelection()`; ignores what comes from `loadDocumentNode()`.

I tried unloading/re-loading the extensions but it still won't work.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for loading multiple models was added later on, and to prevent breaking backwards compatibility, the developers added new APIs and event names that should be used in multi-model scenarios. Look for methods and events with the "aggregate" word in them, for example, [getAggregateSelection](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getaggregateselection-callback), `Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`, or `Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_FIT_TO_VIEW_EVENT`.

Comment: Both issues were solved using getAggregateSelection and AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!